# A problem occurred starting process 'command 'yarn''

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

Hi guys I am trying to run my react-native project on android on a windows machine. I keep getting this error

Configure project :app
Evaluating project ':app' using build file 'E:\React-Native\Lalo_RN\lalo\android\app\build.gradle'.
Reading env from: .env
Starting process 'command 'yarn''. Working directory: E:\React-Native\Lalo_RN\lalo\android Command: yarn run git-info

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'yarn''

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 37s
6 actionable tasks: 6 up-to-date
Watched directory hierarchies: [E:\React-Native\Lalo_RN\lalo\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin]